# Using Google Play Services as a dependency in gradle build

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

Any idea why gradle cannot resolve references to `Google Play Services` lib?

Even after I've added a dependency entry and refreshed my dependencies within `Eclipse` ..

```
AdView cannot be resolved to a type
```

Directory listing inside root project. I'm using `LibGdx`, so each targeted platform is a sub-directory (sub-project).

```
bob@laptop:~/git/game$ ls
android       core     gradle.properties  ios
build         desktop  settings.gradle    build.gradle
```

Snippet from `build.gradle` of the root project `game` ..

```
bob@laptop:~/git/game$ cat build.gradle | grep -A 25 ":android"
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.99'
    }
}
```

Latest version of `Google Play Services` are downloaded into my local sdk ..

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `apply plugin: "android"` was replaced by `apply plugin: "com.android.application"` about a year ago. What version of Gradle and the Gradle for Android plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using `libgdx`, which uses `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably doesn't have the correct version number of Play Services.

Try with 7.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `libgdx`. However, something about your build process seems like it is suppressing build errors and warnings. Unless `apply plugin: "android"` is referring to something other than Google's Gradle for Android plugin, you should be getting at least a warning about that, as that name has been deprecated. More importantly, you should be getting build errors about not finding `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.99'` as a dependency.

Installing what you are pointing to in the SDK Manager screenshot ("Google Play Services") only downloads a local library project, for use by Eclipse (sans Gradle). For a Gradle dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services` in a traditional Android project, you need to install the Google Repository and the Android Repository. At minimum, you do not have the Android Repository installed, per your screenshot. Again, it is possible that `libgdx` has some strange way of handling this that differs from the Android norms.